# NodeJS app best way to process large logic in azure vm

Tags: node.js, express, azure-virtual-machine

I have created a NodeJS express post api which process the file stored in azure blob. In the post call to this api, I am just sending filename in body. This call will get the data from blob, create a local file with that data, run command on that file and store it in blob again. But that command is taking 10-15 mins to process one file. That's why the request is getting timed out. I had 2 questions here:

1. Is there way to respond to the call before processing starts. Like respond to the api call and then start file processing.
2. If 1 is not possible, which is the best solution for this problem

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must use queue for long running tasks. For that you can choose any library like agendajs, bull, bee-queue, kue etc